# Does docker use host's random and timesync

Tags: docker

When I run a docker container, does it use host's `/dev/random` `/dev/urandom` and does it use host's time?
I'm planning to use `haveged` and `ntp`, so is it enough to install them on the host machine, or do I need to somehow install/link them to the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker shares the kernel with the docker host, so devices like /dev/random and time that are provided by the kernel will be handled outside of your container. In fact, if you try to change the time inside of a container, you'll find that docker has removed this capability by default (CAP_SYS_TIME).

```
root@66fd0ad0324e:/# date 06061209
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
```

There is one caveat, if docker is running on a VM like it does with environments like MacOS and Windows, the VM is running the kernel, so you need to ensure its time is correct in that VM. I believe you could do this with a privileged container running the ntp daemon.